# How to tell the object type of an Attachment

Tags: attachment

I need to export all of the attachments of an org. I would like to break them down to be in a folder based upon the object type of their parent. In other words, I want all attachments which are in an Account to be in one single folder, and all of the ones in an Opportunity to be in another folder.

I've been trying to determine how the Attachments are arranged by running queries on the Attachment object in Workbench. But I believe the closest I can come to determining this information is the Attachment object's ParentID field. But that's just the ID of the individual record, not the object type of the Parent. Is there any way to determine the object type of the Parent of the Attachment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a query, you can pull `Parent.Type` in your `SELECT` clause, or even filter on it in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT Body, Parent.Type FROM Attachment
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy, just call `getsobjecttype()` on that Id, and it will return API name of that object.

```
Id parentId= '00161000000Mjya'; 
System.debug('object is '+ parentId.getsobjecttype()); //Returns Account
```

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340200&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thank you very much Pranay. I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that into my query, or my actual export. I'm going to use dataloader.io for the export, and it doesn't really have a way to filter based on that - or at least not from what I see. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on the answer about `getsobjecttype()` :

You can also check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsbIAhhPOu4) which explains how to export attachments from salesforce using NodeJS.

You can adapt the code by adding query filter on object type and organise the file export in appropriate folder.

Hope this helps